# Jquery Post method and JSON issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I'm using jquery and jason sending data to another contoller, but when I send the data, I check it in fire bug and it's fine, It sends it correctly but in the target page, when I var_dump the `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` is returns null.

I'm using codeigniter by the way.

This my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetMovieLanguageCategory(Language) 
{
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "/admin/movie/get_language_category",
  data: JSON.stringify({"Language":Language}),
  success: function(Data)
  {
    alert(Data);
  },
  failure: function(ErrorMsg) {
  alert(ErrorMsg);
  },
}); 
}
</script>
```

And in my Controller:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
//var_dump(json_decode($_POST['Language']));
```

And it returns:

```
array(0) {}
```

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code that would cause the issue you are having. Note however, `failure` should be `error`

Comment: Do you have any other scripts like this that accept json strings via post? I wonder if there's some setting or .htaccess entry messing with your requests.

Comment: No, I tried `contentType: "application/json"` but didn't help!

Comment: I'm using codeigniter, Is anything about htaceess in that about jason?

Comment: Quentin's answer should solve your problem. Look at the link at the bottom. $_REQUEST isn't what you want.

Comment: It didn't! it's Odd, looks like it doesn't send the data, unless it could get it!!!

Comment: `$_REQUEST` only gets populated when you send a query string as either POST or GET.  You are not doing that.  You need to read the *raw* POST body: `$postBody = file_get_contents('php://input');  echo $postBody;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending JSON data, but marking it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded  data and you are trying to parse it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Change:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"Language":Language}),
```

to

```
data:{"Language":Language},
```

and let jQuery encode it properly for you.

---

If you want to encode it yourself (don't!):

```
data: "Language=" + encodeURIComponent(Language);
```

---

If you **really** want to send JSON:

```
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify({"Language":Language}),
```

then, in the PHP, [get the body of the request](/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php) and run it through `json_decode`.

Comment: If that is the issue, using `contentType: "application/json"` would allow him to access it via `$_REQUEST` wouldn't it? i was under the impression that jquery would send it in the request body, and php would give you access to it via `$_REQUEST`

Comment: But I want to send data Using jason, I'm Using compression and If I don't jason encode it, it won't work

Comment: @KevinB — No. PHP will never automatically decode JSON requests.

Comment: no, not auto decode, i expected it to give you the raw json, which it does as you've pointed out, just not in `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @MasOud — I've updated the answer with instructions on how to make a JSON request. (Note "JSON" not "jason", it isn't a singer-songwriter who dated Kylie). I don't see how this would make a difference to being able to compress it though.

Comment: Well, I did the same, The page sends the data correctly as the fire bug says, but the problem is, The other page `$_REQUEST` doesn't get anything and it return a null array

Comment: @MasOud — Of course `$_REQUEST` doesn't get anything. Reread the last line of this answer. Follow the link.